# How can I restore my MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I have my own Ubuntu 16.04 server system and MySQLdb in it. 
And today, I installed MariaDB on the system without noticing installed Mysql. ( with "sudo apt-get install mariadb-server.." command )

I realized there is a mysql-server when finished installing mariadb. 
So, I removed mariadb with "sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server.." command.

And now, I can't access mysql db with error 2002.

How can I fix this situation?

Thanks.

Sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not server administration problems. Try ServerFault.com, askubuntu.com, or dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Error 2002 means MySQL isn't running. Did you start it back up?

Comment: - ceejayoz : the problem is I can't start MySQL

Comment: - Barmar : Sorry, I will move my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that mysql is installed? Per default, mariadb should be installed on ubuntu